# Convert a polygon grid into an edge table

Tags: polygon, network, grids-graticules

I'm working on a robotics project.  I've got a rectangular grid (polygon shapefile) that is a navigable/routable region (i.e. I can travel anywhere in this grid).  That is I took my bounding area subtracted the obstacle areas, then turned that into a grid of polygons.

I'm looking to do path planning with pgRouting, I need to convert this polygon file into an edge network.  I'm on the path of computing point centroids, connecting point to its 6 nearest neighbors into a line segment table (edge network) is there an existing tool?

Comment: do you use a specific software ?